# Wierd error while compiling my program and a module using makefile

Tags: c, makefile

This is the error when I run make:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"\_add", referenced from:
\_main in a4-1-989722.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: \*\*\* \[a4-1\] Error 1
```

note (one of the functions in my module is add()

**This is the makefile:**

```makefile
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
TARGET = a4-1
DEP1 = myMath

all:    $(TARGET)

debug:  CFLAGS += -DDBUG
debug:  $(TARGET)

&(TARGET): $(TARGET).c $(DEP1).o
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEP1).o -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c

$(DEP1).o: $(DEP1).c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(DEP1).c

clean:
rm $(TARGET) *.o
```

This is the module .c file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return(x + y);
}
```

**This is the module .h file:**

```c
int add(int, int);
```

Comment: Please use the Edit link in your question and edit it to have correct formatting: all your newlines are messed up and it's hard to tell what is what.  You don't want to make each line use a fixed-width font individually, you want to create a block of quoted code.  You can do that by indenting each line with 4 spaces.  You can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more help.  Also, please take advantage of the automatic preview feature of your question to make sure it is readable before finishing the edit.  Then we can help!

Comment: Is the name of "the module .c file" in fact `module.c`?  Because in that case, I have no idea what it has to do with the question, as the makefile given does not reference any such file.  For its part, the makefile is either mangled or flat wrong, as each line in the recipe part of a `make` rule must be indented with a leading tab character, and there is no sign of any indentation of any kind in the makefile presented.

Comment: Plus there's a `&` before the `$(TARGET)` rule which is certainly wrong, and the output quoted here has bizarre backslashes before various characters.  Also, it's weird to have a program depend on one `.o` file and one `.c` file, then link together the `.o` with the compiled `.c` file.  It's not wrong, probably, but it's weird.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "module.h"
```

in `module.c`